# Pandas dataframe create a new column based on columns of other dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have these two df's:
df A:

```
ID  TYPE  
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    A
5    C
```

df B:

```
TYPE  MEASURE
A      0.3
B      0.4
C      0.5
```

What I would like to do is add a third column to df A based on the correspondence of df B regarding `TYPE`:

```
ID  TYPE MEASURE
1    A     0.3
2    B     0.4
3    C     0.5
4    A     0.3
5    C     0.5
```

I tried this code:

```
def operation (row):  

RESULT=B.loc[titlevar['TYPE'] == row['TYPE'] ][['MEASURE']].values  
return RESULT

A['MEASURE'] = A.apply (lambda row: operation (row),axis=1)
```

But I think I am making more mistakes. Hopefully somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map for this

```
dfA['MEASURE'] = dfA['TYPE'].map(dfB.set_index('TYPE')['MEASURE'])
```

dfA:

```
    ID  TYPE    MEASURE
0   1   A       0.3
1   2   B       0.4
2   3   C       0.5
3   4   A       0.3
4   5   C       0.5
```

Comment: For some reason when I do this I only obtain a column of NAs in dfA

Comment: Did you check spellings of all the variables? They are all CAPs in the example you provided, may be they are title case or small in the dataframe. I double check and this code works so asking

Comment: It worked! For some reason there was an extra space in my dfB. Thanks so much!